# How can I get features add to Cortana?

Tags: cortana

I live in Sweden and I'd like to speak Swedish with Cortana.

How can I get it prioritised for development, or is there already a release scheduled for this?

Comment: You can vote for it here: http://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/249009-general-cortana-feedback/suggestions/5875330-enable-cortana-in-sweden

Comment: Questions of the form "When will X be available in my country" are [specifically listed as being off topic as speculative](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), given the useful answer, I've reworded your question to be more answerable, to help avoid close votes for you.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is targeting [U.K. and China after the United States](http://www.wpcentral.com/cortana-teased-uk-release). Canada will probably follow soon after.

I suspect market forces will dictate the urgency with which languages are added.

For instance, look at the up votes for Cortana in:

- [Vietnamese](http://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/249009-general-cortana-feedback/suggestions/5877865-add-and-support-vietnamese-language-in-cortana)
- [Turkish](http://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/249009-general-cortana-feedback/suggestions/5876000-add-and-support-turkish-language-in-cortana)
- [Persian](http://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/249009-general-cortana-feedback/suggestions/5875598-add-and-support-persian-language-in-cortana)
- and even [Polish](http://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/249009-general-cortana-feedback/suggestions/5874978-polish-language-in-cortana)

Sweden need to start voting :)

---

Edit 16th June: [Confirmation that U.K. and China will be getting Cortana next](http://www.trustedreviews.com/news/windows-phone-8-1-cortana-release-date-coming-within-weeks)